# vcloud air Java SDK

Tags: vcloud-director-rest-api

Is there any Java SDK Jar is available for developing the vcloud air platform?
I read that there is a way of REST FULL JSON req/resp is using for communication cloud air platform. Is is true?

Answer (score 0):

https://developercenter.vmware.com/web/sdk/5.5.0/vcloud-java

The current vCloud 5.5 SDK can be used to interact with vCloud Air.